# Solr post command always fails with WARNING: Solr return an error 404 for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/core-name/update/extract... for HTML files

Tags: solr

Linux Mint 20.1
Apache Solr 8.11.1

I am able to post XML documents from the examples subdirectory such as *ipod_other.xml*, just not a simple, well formed HTML file I have added to that subdirectory in order to test Solr because I anticipate indexing HTML documents. (Note that this is my first Solr rodeo.)

```
~/dev/solr-8.11.1/example/exampledocs $ ../../bin/post -c gettingstarted  sample.html 
/home/russ/dev/jdk-11.0.10+9/bin/java -classpath /home/russ/dev/solr-8.11.1/dist/solr-core-8.11.1.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=gettingstarted -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool sample.html
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file sample.html (text/html) to [base]/extract
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract?resource.name=%2Fhome%2Fruss%2Fdev%2Fsolr-8.11.1%2Fexample%2Fexampledocs%2Fsample.html&literal.id=%2Fhome%2Fruss%2Fdev%2Fsolr-8.11.1%2Fexample%2Fexampledocs%2Fsample.html
```

In *server/solr/gettingstarted/conf/solrconfig.xml* I have added:

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
```

as suggested elsewhere, but this makes no difference in or out.

I am able to access *http://localhost:8983/solr/#/* and *http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted/core-overview* as well as run queries.

Comment: While it would appear that 8.11.1 doesn't come natively configured to support the TIKA extraction of HTML files, searching for and implementing that request handler and supporting JARs in configuration (which can be found in the contrib directory) appears not to solve this problem anyway.

Comment: You mean you properly registered the `/update/extract` request handler in solrconfig.xml and still get the 404 ?

Comment: Yes, or so I tried to.

Comment: What happens if you direclty ask solr to extract sample.html using curl or the bin/post script ? @see [Extracting Data without Indexing](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#extracting-data-without-indexing)

Comment: I hadn't tried `curl`. I had only been using the `bin/post` script as illustrated in my question. I tried `curl` and it did work. I will use `curl` from now on though disappointed that Solr's proper tool fails in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Oops. At first, I thought `curl` was working, but my query was only finding artifacts put there by a non-HTML version of the sample. As soon as I removed the whole core, recreated it then re indexed sample.html, queries found nothing I looked for. `curl` simply gives a reply that makes it appear that it's working (i.e.: no error, not the warning reported).